# Abp setting manager not reading values from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am using Abp in my .NET Core 3.1 application. The version of Abp is `Abp.AspNetCore(5.10.1)`. I am facing an issue that when i update any setting, the setting get stored in the database but when i read the data, the default value is read and not the value from database.
My code for reading the settings is:

```
var settings = SettingManager.GetAllSettingValuesForTenant(AbpSession.TenantId.Value);
```

If the above settings are null then i use the following code to read the value:

```
var audioPlaybackSetting = _session.TenantId.HasValue
                    ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenant(Consts.AudioPlaybackSetting, _session.TenantId.Value)
                    : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplication(Consts.AudioPlaybackSetting);
```

But this returns the default value and not the value from database.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading from the same database that you are writing to?

Comment: yes, if i set the setting and go back to setting page and then read the setting, it works fine. But, if a set the setting value and dont go back to the setting page and use the setting, it gives me default value. @jdweng

Comment: How are you verifying the good results are getting stored?  With c# or another application.

Comment: I check into the database directly.

Comment: If you are not getting the same results in c# that you are getting from checking directly than you are not looking at the same database or the filtering of the data is different between directly and c#.

Comment: But it works in one case,
If i save a setting, move to some other page and comes back to settings page, i do see the updated settings and these settings also work perfectly wihin the application.
But if i save the settings and try to use them within the apllication, in this case it has a random behaviour i.e. sometimes i get the updated settings and sometimes get the default value.
So i strongly believe this eliminates the different database thing.

Comment: Are you using Entity?  There is a mapping between the c# classes and the database.  When writing new data you should write to the c# classes and then update the database from the c# classes so the data in the classes are the same as the database.

Comment: Are you reading and writing in the same unit of work, or a new unit of work in the same request? Did you call `SaveChanges`?

Comment: I am not using any unit of work. There are only two calls, for saving "ChangeSettingForTenant" and for reteirving  "GetSettingValueForTenant". Both of these calls are in separate API.

Comment: I believe there is some issue with Cache. Do you have any idea how can we clear/refresh Abp cache ? @jdweng

Comment: Do you mean making two API calls via JavaScript on the same page?

Comment: Not on the same page but on different page @aaron

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you share a video/gif with a repro project on GitHub?

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue - sometimes the value returned is the "default" for us, this is usually the testing / staging value, and of course we dont want that value to be returned in our production system. This occurs even after changing the value at the database level in the production system. Very weird.

Comment: Honestly it should read from the database values at startup and then cache those values. Hardcoding them anyway is garbage.

Comment: Abp is internally using cache to save these settings values. I tried disabling the cache and it worked for me i.e. when i retrieve a setting value, i get the updated one. But this approach require disabling the cache which can break other parts of the application. @fullStackChris. I believe Abp should look into this issue and try to rectify it as it is causing issue for many people.